# A machine averages producing $10$ defects per day. What is the probability it will produce more than $15$ defects in a given day?

Tags: probability

Can anyone help me with this?

> A machine averages producing $10$ defects per day. What is the probability it will produce more than $15$ defects in a given day?

Comment: The standard model is Poisson, $\lambda=10$.

Comment: It depends on the matchine's overall rate of production.  A machine that only produces 10 products per day, with a 100% defect rate, will never produce more than 10 defects per day.

Answer (score 4):

This is a possion process with $\lambda=10$.

So what you want to calculate is:

$P(y \ge 15) =1-P(y<15)$

Possion distribution has pdf as $P(y)=\frac{\lambda^ye^{-\lambda}}{y!}$

In this case, $\lambda=10$, so $P(y)=\frac{10^ye^{-10}}{y!}$

So, $P(y\ge 15)=1-P(y<15)=1-(P(1)+P(2)+P(3)+...+P(14))=1-(\frac{10^1e^{-10}}{1!}+\frac{10^2e^{-10}}{2!}+...+\frac{10^14e^{-10}}{14!})=0.08345847$